# about quartz cluster

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I am trying to use quartz cluster.

Is that possible if I have like 5 schedulers registered.
2 schedulers are just responsible for 3 jobdetails. The other 3 schedulers are just responsible for other jobdetails?
Because I have several projects need quartz schedulers.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

- Use Quartz Where features
- Use two clustered schedulers (one cluster of two nodes, one cluster of three nodes)

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. Does this mean I cannot have like two sets of schedulers in same cluster?